# Better way to write spread operator with conditions in javascript

Tags: javascript, object, conditional-statements, spread

I'm looking for a better way to write the following code:

```
let fromCreatedAt;
let toCreatedAt = new Date();

const someObject = {
    ...((!!fromCreatedAt || !!toCreatedAt) ? {
        createdAt: {
            ...(!!fromCreatedAt ? {
                from: fromCreatedAt,
            } : {}),
            ...(!!toCreatedAt ? {
                to: toCreatedAt,
            } : {}),
        },
    } : {}),
}

console.log(someObject); // { createdAt: { to: 2020-11-18T05:32:57.697Z } }
```

fromCreatedAt and toCreatedAt are variables that can change and generate a different object.

This is just an example, but you could have an object that repeats the conditions of the createdAt field multiple times for other fields, so you would find a way to refactor that repeated functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create objects using [shorthand property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015) and conditionally spread it

```js
let fromCreatedAt,
    toCreatedAt = new Date(),
    from = fromCreatedAt,
    to = toCreatedAt;

const createdAt = {
      ...(from && { from }),
      ...(to && { to })
    },
    someObject = {
      ...(from || to && { createdAt })
    }

console.log(someObject)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd use shorthand properties to create the `createdAt` nested object, removing undefined values by filtering through `Object.fromEntries`. Then you can create the `someObject` depending on whether the `createdAt` object has any keys or not:

```js
let from;
let to = new Date();
const createdAt = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries({ from, to }).filter(([, val]) => val !== undefined)
);

const someObject = Object.keys(createdAt).length
  ? { createdAt }
  : {};
  
console.log(someObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `...null` and `...undefined` will cause no data properties to be copied, you could get rid of the ternary operators and simplify to boolean short-circuit evaluation:

```js
let fromCreatedAt;
let toCreatedAt = new Date();

const someObject = {
  ...(fromCreatedAt || toCreatedAt) && {
    createdAt: {
      ...fromCreatedAt && { from: fromCreatedAt},
      ...toCreatedAt && { to: toCreatedAt},
    }
  }
};

console.log(someObject);
```

I thought this might be a little more elegant, but it doesn't get rid of the duplicate conditions, so probably doesn't answer the question completely.